# if-statement PHP using multiple strings

Tags: php, string, if-statement

How can I use two or more strings?

This is what I'm using to do just one string.

```
if ($input == "test")
{
    echo "$imput is equal to test.";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this might work best if you have many strings to compare with.

```
$string = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
foreach ($string as $s) {
    if ($input == $s) {
        echo "$input is equal to $s";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
if ($input == "test" && $input2 == "hello")
{
    echo "$input is equal to test and input2 is equal to hello.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean how can you check if two strings contain a certain value?

If so, just use &&:

```
if($input == "test" && $input2 == "test") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use

```
foreach ($dataarray as $string) {
   if ($input == $string) {
       echo "Match Found";
       break;
    }
 }
```

Then it results Match Found if it founds the string in the array $dataarray();